# Passing Unicode parameters in Microsoft Flow using execute stored procedure (v2) task

Tags: sql-server, powerapps, power-automate

Need to run the below procedure using Flow

```sql
exec sp_set_firewall_rule N'Ashish_Test', '0.0.0.3', '0.0.0.3';
```

i am using following task to run it

[image: image showing the flow task]

but i get the following error

```
"The parameters supplied for the procedure "sp_set_firewall_rule" are not valid."
```

this is the same error i get when running the following on sql server directly

```
exec sp_set_firewall_rule 'Ashish_Test', '0.0.0.3', '0.0.0.3';
```

the extended proc expects the first parameter as unicode but how do i define it in flow?

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-set-firewall-rule-azure-sql-database) says, _This is an extended stored procedure, so the data type of the value passed in for each parameter must match the parameter definition._ If you can't convince Microsoft Flow to use exact data types (such as `nvarchar(128)` for the first parameter) have you considered wrapping the call to `master.sys.sp_set_firewall_rule` in a stored procedure of your own creation and invoking that from Flow instead?

Comment: You could create a task for "Execute a SQL query" with the "Query" as `exec sp_set_firewall_rule N'Ashish_Test', '0.0.0.3', '0.0.0.3';`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning i had tried updating the table using my own proc but that is not allowed since it is a system catalog. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a task for "Execute a SQL query" with the "Query" text as

```
exec sp_set_firewall_rule N'Ashish_Test', '0.0.0.3', '0.0.0.3';
```